# I could not connect to SQL Server using SQL Operations Studio. azure

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-mac, azure-data-studio

Issue Type: Bug

I could not connect to SQL Server using SQL Operations Studio. In firewall, I already add my IP address but this software does not detect it.

SQL Operations Studio version: sqlops 0.30.6 (df7e3ec, 2018-06-19T21:34:32.192Z)
OS version: Darwin x64 17.5.0

System Info
Extensions: none

Comment: This is not a bug/issue database, try reporting your issue on one of the Developer Community boards :  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Comment: In what way could you not connect? Mouse fell apart? screen went dark? Post an error message. "could not connect" is a singularly useless description.

Comment: are you SURE you used the correct iP address?  Do NOT use your locally assigned IP, you need to use the external IP assigned by your provider.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, have you verified network connectivity (e,g, `TELNET yourazuresqldatabase.database.windows.net 1433`)? Once you've done due diligence, [report SOS issues on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio).

Comment: To Jason I exactly used the external IP assigned by my provider. My error is like that Error adding account : Error: Entry not found in cache.

Comment: Please ping the IP address of your Azure SQL Server. it should fail but let me know if it returns the name of your Azure SQL Server. Here we are testing DNS resolution.

Comment: Don't use an IP. You need to use an address in the form shown: `yourazuresqldatabase.database.windows.net. Assuming this is a SQL Azure database and not some other incarnation. Again there is not enough info in the question to assist in any way